# Iterate through dataset get child rows

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this.

I am trying to iterate through an xml file and get each "table" in the xml file, and get each child rows etc.

I am able to get the rows that are not child rows etc just fine.

Here is an example of the xml structure.

```
<items>
    <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <row1>abc</row1>
    <row2>abc</row2>
    <needthis>
       <first>John</first>
       <last>John</last>
    </needthis>
    </item>
</items>
```

This is what I am currently using.

```
 foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
 {
   foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
   {
     foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
     {
        object item = row["id"];
        object item2 = row["row1"];
        //Just to see what is returning
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(item2.ToString());
      } 
    }
  }
```

What would I need to get the first row and last row of needthis table?

Comment: Did you try [DataRow.GetChildRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.getchildrows(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a dataset rather than just parsing out the XML? That seems like it would be an easier way to maintain.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I'm all for what makes more sense and easier. This is the first time I have had to read/parse and xml file using C#, and is the first example I came across that seemed to work till I got to needing the child rows etc.

Comment: @Bowenac yeah, you might want to look into [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx). It's just a little more direct way of doing what you want, so it might be easier. And more expandable, too.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen will do, I need to find my C# book or a better example all the examples from MS make my brain hurt as they don't seem that great.

Comment: @Bowenac I put in an example below of how to use `XElement` to read the schema you gave us.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I like Linq to XML for this kind of thing.

```
//Probably want to use Load if you're using a file
XDocument xDoc = 
        XDocument.Parse (@" 
        <items>
            <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <row1>abc</row1>
            <row2>abc</row2>
            <needthis>
            <first>John</first>
            <last>John</last>
            </needthis>
            </item>
        </items>");

var items = from item in xDoc.Descendants("item") 
            from needThis in item.Descendants("needthis")
            select new 
            {       Id = item.Element("id").Value,
                    Row1 = item.Element("row1").Value,
                    first = needThis.Element("first").Value,
                    last = needThis.Element("last").Value
            };

foreach (var item in items)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
     Console.WriteLine(item.Row1);
     Console.WriteLine(item.first);
     Console.WriteLine(item.last);
}
```

If for some reason you really needed to use datasets you will need to do the following

1. Not loop over the DataTable collection but just use the item Table
2. Use GetChildRows using the DataRelation "item_needthis" You can find the data relation name by inspecting the DataSet.Relations Collection

```
using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(@" 
            <items>
                <item>
                <id>1</id>
                <row1>abc</row1>
                <row2>abc</row2>
                <needthis>
                <first>John</first>
                <last>John</last>
                </needthis>
                </item>
            </items>");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(stream);


   DataTable table = ds.Tables["item"];

   foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
   {
        Console.WriteLine( row["id"] );
        Console.WriteLine( row["row1"] );
        var ChildRows = row.GetChildRows("item_needthis"); 
        foreach(var ntRow in ChildRows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( ntRow["first"]);
            Console.WriteLine( ntRow["last"]);
        }
   }


}
```

You could also use Linq to Datasets

Comment: @Bowenac no problem. I also added an answer for your stated question just in case someone else runs across this question and needed to use datasets

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead of DataSets. Then you could read your file even with just this:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(...); // or Parse(...)

return root.Elements("item").Select(c => new { id = c.Element("id").Value,
                                               row1 = c.Element("row1").Value,
                                               row2 = c.Element("row2").Value,
                                               needthis = new { first = c.Element("needthis").Element("first").Value,
                                                                last = c.Element("needthis").Element("last").Value } });
```

Of course I haven't tested this, but you can see the point. It also doesn't have any error handling, and it could be more efficient, but again you can see the gist of how it works.